# dotnet build does not create `csproj.metaproj` files needed for Travis CI

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, travis-ci, csproj

I have just started to use Travis CI to build a project on git hub but according to [Travis build output log](https://travis-ci.org/dibley1973/OpenRMS/builds/276436364) Travis seems to be looking for `csproj.metaproj` which are not being created. How do I either:

- Get dotnet build to create the `csproj.metaproj` files

or

- Stop travis needing the `csproj.metaproj` files

And which is the better solution?

My travis yml file looks like this:

```
language: csharp
dist: trusty
mono: none
sudo: required
dotnet: 2.0.0
script:
  - ./build.sh --quiet verify
before_install:
  - chmod +x build.sh
```

My build.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dotnet restore && dotnet build
dotnet test Code\Shared\ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel\ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel.csproj
```

**EDIT:**

Based upon answer by Tomasz Żmuda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261344/dotnet-build-does-not-create-csproj-metaproj-files-needed-for-travis-ci/46261564#46261564), my `build.sh` file now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dotnet restore
dotnet clean -c Release
dotnet build OpenRMS.sln -c Release
```

and my `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
language: csharp
dist: trusty
sudo: required
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
solution: OpenRMS.sln
branches:
  only:
    - master-net-core
before_script:
  - chmod +x build.sh
  - chmod +x test.sh
script:
  - ./build.sh
```

and as of [this build](https://travis-ci.org/dibley1973/OpenRMS/builds/276449356) those changes worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script doesn't work even on normal machine :)
The easiest way to make this working it to change

```
dotnet build
```

to

```
dotnet build Code/Shared/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel/
```

so your script should be looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dotnet restore
dotnet build Code/Shared/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel/
dotnet test Code/Shared/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel.UnitTests/
```

I suggest to add some flags to dotnet build lika release build and assembly version. Check this file:
[build.sh](https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/blob/master/build.sh)

Comment: So do I need to have a `dotnet build Code/Shared/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel/` line for each project in my solution? Can i not just tell it to build the solution and all projects within it?

Comment: Using information based upon your answer it now builds so thank you. I'll update my question to include my solution.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helping :)
You shoud add "-c Release" to "dotnet build OpenRMS.sln" command too.

Comment: Okeedoke. Will do I certainly back at machine. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't change question to provide the solution, answer your own question.